# Difference between dynamic arrays (GCC) and pointers

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Considering following pieces of code:

```
void foo() {
    int arraySize = getMyComputedValue();
    int dynamicArray[arraySize];

    fillDynamicArray(&dynamicArray[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        // Do something with data
    }
}

void bar() {
    int arraySize = getMyComputedValue();
    int* dynamicArray = new int[arraySize];

    fillDynamicArray(dynamicArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        // Do something with data
    }

    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = NULL;
}
```

Both create a dynamic area in memory with varying lengths containing integers.
I've found that the first example *foo()* (at least in my build environment) only compiles with GCC.

What are the exact differences between the two? Is the first example merely a GNU extension which is *shorthand* for the bottom example, allowing the compiler to determine when the correct time for de-allocation is? 
Or does the first example do exactly as the code says and allocates the memory on the stack?

Comment: Dynamic arrays (also known as [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) are an optional feature of C99 but not part of C++ standard. Some compilers like gcc provide it as native extension but I wouldn't rely in C++ on them (if code shall be portable C++).

Comment: VLAs are supported only in a specific standard of C (98 if I remember correctly). They are not supported in previous standards of C, and AFAIK not supported in C++ either.

Comment: A relevant difference is that `new[]` can throw `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Btw. `std::vector<int>` provides the nicer alternative to `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Comment: @Scheff, I'm aware, maybe my example was sub-par. This question came to mind as I come from a C#/managed language background and in C++ I work a lot with raw data; so I'm using uint8_t arrays quite a lot.

Comment: @Scheff If my memory serves me correctly, VLAs were *mandatory* in C99, but were demoted to being optional in C11. I guess, that the demotion is mostly due to the complexity of implementation and the fact that C aims to be the language for every possible hardware out there, however limited that hardware might be. As such, ease of implementing a conforming compiler is a core concern for the language.

Comment: I got your point. Though, `std::vector<>::data()` gives you access to the raw data if necessary. It's a pointer to a contiguous storage - just like an array allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: @cmaster Yepp. The Wikipedia link mentioned it less sloppy than me... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `foo()` allocates the memory on the stack, `bar()` allocates it on the heap. This has two effects: Lifetime (stack memory is automatically reclaimed at function exit), and max array size (stack space is rather limited to a range of a few MB at most, heap space is only limited by available RAM).
2. `foo()` is valid C99, but not C++ of any standard. C++ simply never embraced VLAs. This is the core point where you need to realize that C and C++ are two quite distinct languages. There are valid C programs that are not C++ (like `foo()`), and there are valid C++ programs that are not C (like `bar()`). C++ is not the strict superset anymore as which it started.

Nevertheless, compilers may choose to implement a superset of the language as an extension. `g++` does so, but if you compile with strict C++ standard compliance (`g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Werror`), even `g++` throws an error on `foo()`.

Comment: I'm aware they are two different languages. Sadly it's not always clear which functions belong to which specific language, especially when the compiler freely accepts and translated the code.

But thanks for the hint! I'll be sure to keep it in mind

Comment: @SimonC I think `-Wc++-compat` flag could help with that in GCC, but I'm not sure what's the scope of it's warnings. It's supposed to warn about C constructs not available in C++.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'd use `g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Werror` to get strict standard compliance (I've updated my answer to mention this option set).